# MacOS(Catalina): permanent port forwarding

Tags: macos, ssh, port-forwarding, macos-catalina

How can I do a permanent port forwarding on my Mac Catalina:

- it will run on background
- it will work after reboot
- FW is off

Today I use command:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5901 localhost
```

But it runs on foreground and closes after computer restart. So, I need something like this command BUT with 3 requirements that I wrote above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that I found the possible solution for me:

1. `sudo touch /etc/pf-xxx.conf`
2. Write to the file(/etc/pf-xxx.conf): I did it for my vnc ports

   rdr pass inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 port 5901 -> 127.0.0.1 port 5900

   rdr pass inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 port 5902 -> 127.0.0.1 port 5900
3. Create & edit com.apple.pfctl-xxx.plist
   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
   <key>Disabled</key>
   <false/>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.apple.pfctl-xxx</string>
   <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
   <string>/var/run</string>
   <key>Program</key>
   <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
       <string>pfctl</string>
       <string>-e</string>
       <string>-f</string>
       <string>/etc/pf-xxx.conf</string>
   </array>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>`
4. `sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl-xxx.plist`
5. `sudo chmod o-w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl-xxx.plist`
6. `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl-xxx.plist`

The links that I used:

- https://gist.github.com/novemberborn/aea3ea5bac3652a1df6b
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308182/how-to-launch-pf-at-startup
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063598/error-while-executing-plist-file-path-had-bad-ownership-permissions